# Подключиться к серверу

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Абсолютно глупый вопрос, не могу разобраться, что мне подставить, чтобы наконец подключиться к базе? Пароля нет.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
server = "DMITRY-PC\SQLEXPRESS"
dbname = "RGSNEW1"
uname = "DMITRY-PC\Dmitry"
pword = ""
eng = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://" + uname + ":" + pword + "@" + server + "/" + dbname + "?driver=SQL+Server")
```

Другим способом подключался так, но нужно первым:

```
import pyodbc
server = 'DMITRY-PC\SQLEXPRESS'
database = 'RGSNEW1'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Скрин подключения https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WK0X2U_YDCx-0jFW9cLvxeUc6fe0VEyZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал таким образом:

```
eng = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://DMITRY-PC\SQLEXPRESS/RGSNEW1?driver=SQL+Server')
```